# Vue 3: v-for displaying more components than items?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am new to Vue and playing around a bit. I am also using ionic, which I am also new to.
I have my own component `<trip.card>` that I want to display for each trip instance I get back from my API:

```
<template>
  <ion-page>
    <ion-content :fullscreen="true">
      <ion-header collapse="condense">
        <ion-toolbar>
          <ion-title size="large">Woadie - Trips</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
      <trip-card v-for="trip in trips" ref="trips" :tripName="trip.name" />
    </ion-content>
  </ion-page>
</template>
```

From what I gathered from docs I can now use onMounted to set my data:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import {
  IonContent,
  IonHeader,
  IonPage,
  IonTitle,
  IonToolbar,
} from "@ionic/vue";
import TripCard from "./TripCard.vue";
import axios from "axios";
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
const trips = ref([]);
onMounted(() => {
  axios.get("http://localhost:8081/woadie/trips").then((response) => {
    trips.value = response.data;
  });
});
</script>
```

Now, my API returns an array with one trip instance. However, the `<trip-card>`component is displayed much more often, than just once. Why could that be?

In the docs I have found this snippet:

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

const list = ref([
  /* ... */
])

const itemRefs = ref([])

onMounted(() => console.log(itemRefs.value))
</script>

<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in list" ref="itemRefs">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

The difference to my implementation appears to be the `const list = ref([])` and `<li v-for="item in list" ref="itemRefs">` instead of using itemRefs directly. Why is that? What does that extra step do? It's not explained in the docs and I don't understand why it would be necessary.

Comment: Remove the `ref="trips"`, it creates a [template ref](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html) in the variable you use for the data. In general, don't use template refs unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ref `itemRefs` will contain all of your `<li>` rendered by `v-for`. Not your `list`'s elements.

It's called a template ref:

https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html